# How can I change the Bluemix documentation?

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb, sqldb

I found that the Bluemix documentation is wrong in an example of the SQLDB service and I ran into an issue. I was able to fix it myself. How can I change the Bluemix documentation? How do I submit feedback and get the docs fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the documentation is possible in two ways:

1. On the right side of each page of the Bluemix documentation (available at e.g. https://www.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/ and other regions) is a `Feedback` button. Click it and you are able to select whether it is general feedback or specific to parts of that page. If you choose `specific feedback` you could then pick the region of that documentation that needs an update or you would like to submit a comment on. A form is presented where you can leave your feedback. For "general feedback" you are first presented with an emoticon. After picking how you like the documentation a form appears where you can type in your comments and categorize them.
2. Another form of documentation enhancement is possible by submitting changes directly against the [Bluemix documentation hosted on github](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/docs). Fork the documentation, edit the files you want and submit a pull request for your changes to be merged back into the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You should see a "Feedback" label on the right in each page of the Docs. Clicking on it you will be able to submit a feedback on the specific page or the Bluemix Docs in general. You can also insert your comments on the possible errors.